# What does this Verb+Noun structure mean and how to use it?

Tags: syntax

So my friend told me this:

> 温室で死ぬ時が来た

I understand that the translation means "It's time to die in the greenhouse", but I don't understand the 「死ぬ時」 part of the sentence.

What kind of structure is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a relative clause. You might translate it as "The time has come, where (I) die in the greenhouse" or "The time to [die in the greenhouse] has come".

It's split up the following way:

> 温室で死ぬ - die in the greenhouse
>   時が来た - time has come

Literally "Die-in-the-greenhouse time has come".

English has signal words that introduce a relative clause, whereas Japanese does not. It's just a normal sentence directly in front of a noun.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its kind of confusing without of the indication marks :L

Comment: @Mavain: Yeah, relative clauses like this where also one of my major stumbling points in the beginning. You get used to them after a while though, I found.